# Не отображается swagger-ui.html в open-api на сервере

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

Использую Spring-Boot 2.x.x, gradle 6, Java 8

И хотел перейти с Swagger 2 на Open api (Swagger 3)
В Swagger 2 таких проблем не было

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.3')
}
```

и swagger-ui.html доступен по адресу

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

но на сервере в контейнере сервис доступен по адресу

```
http://serverX/api-name/...
```

Там open-api documentation уже не работает (503)

```
http://serverX/api-name/swagger-ui.html
```

если добавить в адрес редиректа

```
http://serverX/api-name/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=http:http://serverX/api-name/api-docs/swagger-config/
```

то странца Open api отразится без содержимомго

наконец, если добавить в строку с Explore

```
/api-name/api-docs
```

а не просто

```
/api-docs
```

то всё заработает

Так себе путь, может кто сталкивался, как задать адрес сервера и название апи так, чтобы swagger-ui был доступен по ссылке в контейнере Docker в Kubernetes:

```
http://serverX/api-name/swagger-ui.html
```